# Javascript regex urls that are not image extensions

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following JavaScript which matches and replaces URLS with html links, however I need this to exclude urls which end in .png|.jpg|.jpeg|.gif

```
text = text.replace(
            /(\b(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim,
            '<a href="$1" class="autolink" target="_blank">$1</a>'
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just to a test before:

```
if (!text.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/) {
    text = text.replace(
            /(\b(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim,
            '<a href="$1" class="autolink" target="_blank">$1</a>'
        );
}
```

If you need to do multiple replacements, then you could use a custom replace function that checks the match against the image endings and acts accordingly.  That would work like this:

```
var imageRegex = /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/;
text = text.replace(/(\b(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[a-z0-9-+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim, 
    function(str) {
        if (str.match(imageRegex)) {
            return(str);
        } else {
            return('<a href="' + str + '" class="autolink" target="_blank">' + str + '</a>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, something like this would work for input with a single url however my input can have many urls in the string. Thanks ayway

Comment: You could use a custom replacement function that examines the matched string, compares it to the image regex and then decides whether to just leave it alone (replace it with itself) or linkify it.  If this is supposed to be general purpose linkifying code and you're trying to avoid <img src=xxx"> links, then you probably also have all sorts of other things to avoid too (like <script src=xxx"> and <a href="xxx">).

Comment: I added an example of a custom replacement function.